# Vue - wait until necessary data is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want my app to wait for necessary data before users can interact. I need to be sure that things like `store.state.currentUser` are already loaded otherwise application doesn't work properly.

How can I do that?

**App.vue**

```
...
  mounted() {

    this.$store.dispatch("loadUsers")
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchCurrentUser")
    this.$store.dispatch("loadSupplierCategories")
    this.$store.dispatch("loadSuppliers")
    ...
  }
```

Is there some best practice or a common way to make the app waiting for the data?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "waiting". You could put `isLoading` boolean variables into the state and set the app interface to readonly, displaying a loading indicator, until `isLoading` switches to false.

Comment: You  could also dispatch sequentially all your actions by using `async` and `await`, you have some examples here: https://lukashermann.dev/writing/how-to-use-async-await-with-vuejs-components/